# Pyinstaller lib was not found; OSError: [WinError 126]; library dependencies

Tags: python, pyinstaller, spacy, pysimplegui

I really like to be helped.
I made a graphic interface with PysimpleGUI. In this script, i run a program where, from speech recognitioin library and a spaCy pipeline, name entities are caught, and then passed as input for the rest of the script (basically, taking data from a pandas dataframe, doing some math and updating dataset).
I use PyCharm as IDE and works.
The spaCy pipeline is retrain to catch additional labels i did. The new model is saved in the same project folder of the scripts and loaded when needed (basically, there is one window where you push a button and speak; speech is detected and you click another button to pass the text into the pipeline who extract the labels).

When i try to create the .exe of this file, both with PySimpleGUI-exemaker and Pyinstaller, i have the some errors. When use PyInstaller, with "onefolder" option, and i launch the .exe file created (into the dist folder) i see this:

```
C:\Users\Simone>C:\Python_Project\Combat_Workshop\Vocal_Workshop\dist\vocal_menu\vocal_menu.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vocal_menu.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "voice_recognition.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "estrazione_input.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "spacy\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "thinc\api.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "thinc\initializers.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "thinc\backends\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "thinc\backends\ops.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "thinc\util.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "torch\__init__.py", line 135, in <module>
OSError: [WinError 126] Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato. Error loading "C:\Python_Project\Combat_Workshop\Vocal_Workshop\dist\vocal_menu\torch\lib\caffe2_detectron_ops_gpu.dll" or one of its dependencies.
[4568] Failed to execute script 'vocal_menu' due to unhandled exception!
```

I really can't understand what happens here:

```
OSError: [WinError 126] Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato. Error loading "C:\Python_Project\Combat_Workshop\Vocal_Workshop\dist\vocal_menu\torch\lib\caffe2_detectron_ops_gpu.dll" or one of its dependencies.
[4568] Failed to execute script 'vocal_menu' due to unhandled exception!
```

First line is traslated as: OSError: [WinError 126] Impossible to find the module

Then, if i try to create as "onefile", these warnings occur during the running of PyInstaller from the console:

```
102276 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
103138 WARNING: lib not found: torch_python.dll dependency of c:\users\simone\anaconda3\envs\deep_learning2\lib\site-packages\torch\_C.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
103300 WARNING: lib not found: torch_cpu.dll dependency of c:\users\simone\anaconda3\envs\deep_learning2\lib\site-packages\torchvision\_C.pyd
103304 WARNING: lib not found: torch_cuda.dll dependency of c:\users\simone\anaconda3\envs\deep_learning2\lib\site-packages\torchvision\_C.pyd
103310 WARNING: lib not found: c10.dll dependency of c:\users\simone\anaconda3\envs\deep_learning2\lib\site-packages\torchvision\_C.pyd
103313 WARNING: lib not found: c10_cuda.dll dependency of c:\users\simone\anaconda3\envs\deep_learning2\lib\site-packages\torchvision\_C.pyd
103684 WARNING: lib not found: torch_cpu.dll dependency of c:\users\simone\anaconda3\envs\deep_learning2\lib\site-packages\torchaudio\_torchaudio.pyd
103689 WARNING: lib not found: c10.dll dependency of c:\users\simone\anaconda3\envs\deep_learning2\lib\site-packages\torchaudio\_torchaudio.pyd
```

When i launch the .exe file (from dist folder) i get this warning instead:

```
[388] WARNING: file already exists but should not: C:\Users\Simone\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI3882\torch\_C.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
```

Now, in the project folder, i put the model saved from spaCy pipeline. The "dist" folder created is 1GB large. I put there any .py files i need to run the script.
When i did the same things with another script (without any Neural Network), everything worked like charm, so i think the problem is some torch or cuda library.
I have installed both pytorch (via conda) and CUDA 10, and on PyCharm everything works.Have last version of PyCharm and Anaconda.

Now, i tried to look for answer from the past 3 hours, but at this point i give up.
I really don't know what to do. Any help?

edit: After hours i understood one thing: the torch libs not found, are because spacy and pytorch in the same conda enviroment create that warnning when PyInstaller compiles. I'm creating 2 conda envs, one for spaCy, one for Pytorch

Answer (score 0):

I solved after something like 10 hours. Pytorch and spaCy in the same conda env created some problems.
I solved it creating a second env where pytorch is present and spacy isn't.

The other problem was caused by speech recognition library. It's seems that trying to onefile the exe will make it crash.
In the end, i onefolder with no command window and everything worked good (even thou, the app is 1 GB large)